# What can I replace a Shimano SL-M760 shift lever with?

Tags: shimano, shifter, replacement

My right-hand Shimano SL-M760 9-speed shift lever broke, and unfortunately I can't seem to find a new one online (I'm in Germany).

I'm a bit overwhelmed by the number of Shimano 9-speed shift levers available: SL-M370, SL-M390, SL-M580, SL-M590, SL-M770, SL-M970 all seem to do pretty much the same thing.

Differences in quality notwithstanding, could I use any Shimano mountain bike 9-speed shift lever to replace my SL-M760, or are only particular models compatible?

Comment: Any 9 speed Shimano mountain shifter will work as a replacement. All Shimano 9 speed both mountain and road have same cable pull.

Comment: Be sure to order a shifter compatible with your brake levers. I-spec shifters mount to the brake lever. Non I spec clamp to the bars. There are also shifters that are part of the brake lever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Batman's comment ("Any 9 speed Shimano mountain shifter will work as a replacement. All Shimano 9 speed both mountain and road have same cable pull.") I went ahead and got an SL-M590. It works perfectly well as a replacement for my SL-M760.